# Why the Error in jquery: Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jira-rest-api, namespace-organisation

Here is the code and i am getting the error in chrome console as follows:
**Failed to load URL:** **Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var username = "username";

    var password = "password";

    $.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url:'URL',
    dataType:'json',
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
          xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password));
           },
      success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            $('#keepithere').append('<p>'+data+'</p>');
      }

    });
});
```

Comment: when you try an ajax-call to a different url than the current one, jQ will do a preflight: send an options request to the server and see what http verbs are allowed and if this origin is allowed. Now it looks like your server doesn't respond accordingly.

Comment: I suppose this `url:'URL',` is not your real code?

Comment: Yes it is my company website URL and when i  use  that Url in post man i am getting the json response data but when i use the same in the ajax i am not getting the data.But i can't reveal my company url.but it would look like http://jira3.companyname.com/rest/api/2/search?jql=somethings

Comment: If you inspect the preflight request in the network tab, what do you see?

Comment: @AnthonyC  yeah i inspected the console and network tab. for my jira URL i found it as                                                                   Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 302 Found with yellow color dot

Comment: That's the problem. It should return 200 with corresponding CORS headers in the response.

Comment: So now what I have to do?When I use the same URL in postman i am getting the json response and in ajax why it is showing the 302 code?

Comment: It's then a problem on the server side. Either you load your  html/js from the same url or you have to change how the server responds.

Comment: Do you have access to the API? The change is needed to make on the server side. If you have no way to modify it, there will be whole lot more to work on it.

Comment: I don't have access to API. Please suggest the way that i am ready to work what ever it is. @AnthonyC

Comment: You will have to host a proxy server to be the middle man so it handles the requests coming from your app and send the request to the API.

Comment: How to host a proxyserver to get the middle man for my app? I have searched it on google and bing but I did not get any good explanatory result. Can you please provide any resource.Thanks in Advance    
      Mr. @AnthonyC